# F10, F11, & F12 keys not allowed Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

Tags: 18.04, keyboard, function-keys

I was just doing coding and needed to see the source code of my web-page, as I pressed F12 key, It didn't work and shown me the now allowed sign as given in below image. Then I tried other keys, I found that F10 and F11 is also not working. The keys are not working anywhere in the system.

[image]

Comment: Are you using a laptop that has additional functions on the F keys (e.g. change volume/brightness, mute, etc.)?

Comment: I'm using a desktop, But yes It has a Function key and all the keys are working as it should. Only these Three keys are not working. I tried it with Function key too but did not work.

Comment: please run `sudo evtest`, select your keyboard and press F12. Does an `EV_KEY` event show up? If yes, which key (the `KEY_...` value in parentheses)?

Answer (score 0):

The `F` keys have two functions each, one is the shortcuts we know and use, and one is the built in with the manufacturer, in the BIOS there is a setting to which of the 2 is the default, i.e. which one will execute when you press one of the `F` keys, and the other use is accessed via pressing `fn`+`F?`.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. While your answer is basically correct when talking about laptops, it doesn't answer the question because: the OP said they have a desktop PC and I highly doubt that it has such configuration in its firmware (since there is no built-in keyboard). The OP also stated that they tried pressing the keys in conjunction with the Fn key, but it didn't make a difference.

Comment: On Desktops the keys are wired as well with or without the `fn` keys. I didn't see the OPs comment regarding using the `fn` key as well...

Answer (score 0):

If it connects via a USB cable or similar, unplug the device and then plug it in again and see if it works.

Ref: https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/power-suspendfail.html.en

This works for me in Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS. Usually, after the system suspends, I see this issue along with a few other issues with Wifi, sound etc. Once the system is restarted all works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 with a wired keyboard, and encountered the same question.

In my keyboard, hotkeys `Fn`+`F10`~`F12` control video playing. But if there is no video captured, when I press `Fn`+`F10` (any of `F10~F12`), the `NO` window pops up as the attached image in the OP.

There is also a hotkey `Fn`+`Esc` to enable / disable Hotkey mode. If we enable Hotkey mode, `F10` acts like `Fn`+`F10`. Therefore, we may get `NO` window in this mode by pressing the single key `F10`, `F11` or `F12`.

**I guess you are in Hotkey mode.** Press `Fn`+`Esc` to exit the mode.