# Function keys hijacked

Tags: keyboard-layout, ubuntu-gnome

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04. One major annoyance is that the function keys are somehow hijacked by Ubuntu and mapped to media actions. I use CLion (coding IDE) a lot and F10 is mapped to 'Step over' in the debugger, but because the system maps it to muting the headphones, the IDE never sees F10. Does anyone know how to disable the hijacking, so F10 becomes F10 again?

Thank you,

Comment: Usually you can manually override it by holding the function key at the same time as pressing the f1 f2 etc. If you look in the system keyboard settings there should be an option to choose which way the OS uses the function keys by default.

Comment: @rohtua Doesn't work. I probably should have added that I use a desktop, not a laptop and that I use a Mac keyboard (on of the old aluminum ones). Using evtest, I get for F10: type 1 (EV_KEY), code 113 (KEY_MUTE), value 0

Comment: I have the exact same problem as here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1114091/f10-f11-f12-key-now-allowed-ubuntu-18-04-1-lts