# Keyboard stops working and a "No" symbol is on the screen

Tags: 20.04, keyboard

My laptop keyboard suddenly stops working after showing a notification sign, then starts working after I press the <kbd>Super</kbd> key. The attached image shows the notification that I'm seeing:

[image: The Interrupt Sign]

How can I resolve this?

and my system's chassis type i.e.
`cat /sys/class/dmi/id/chassis_type`
is `10`

Comment: Did you try to reboot? What key did you press before showing the sign?

Comment: Can you update your question to include the output of `cat /sys/class/dmi/id/chassis_type`? Depending on what kind of chassis you have, there's a possibility that Ubuntu thinks your notebook is a tablet, then disables the keyboard to prevent "accidental keypresses".

Comment: @Emoji i have tried rebooting, and i have not pressed any perticular key before this sign.

Comment: As I answered [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1114091/f10-f11-f12-key-now-allowed-ubuntu-18-04-1-lts/1505851#1505851), maybe you are in Hotkey mode. Depending on your keyboard, `Super`+`Esc` may exit it.

Answer (score 6):

This is something I've seen at work for people using Acer, Toshiba, and HP notebooks. There's a bug in some of the recent 5.x kernels that makes Ubuntu think you're using your notebook in tablet mode, which then disables the keyboard. Pressing <kbd>Super</kbd> or one of the <kbd>F#</kbd> keys can sometimes restore the ability to type, but it's neither permanent nor something anyone wants to deal with.

Fortunately, you can work around the issue by blocking `intel_vbtn` from being loaded. Here's how:

0. Open Terminal (if it's not already open)
1. Create a new `.conf` file in `/etc/modprobe.d/`:

   ```
   sudo vi /etc/modprobe.d/block-intel_vbtn.conf
   ```

   <sub>**Note:** Feel free to use a different editor of your choosing.</sub>
2. Add this to the file:

   ```
   # This module interferes with the keyboard in 5.x kernels. Do not load.
   blacklist intel_vbtn
   ```
3. Save the file
4. Reboot

If a later kernel resolves the issue, you can delete the file and everything will carry on just as it should.

Comment: I am using Lenovo and I am having this issue since 2 Oct 2021 Kernel update

Answer (score 2):

Another solution that worked for me :

During boot I am presented with the following screen -

[image]

By pressing <kbd>down</kbd> key I move the highlighted bar to `Advanced options for Ubuntu` -

[image]

I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and I am presented with the following screen -

[image]

By pressing <kbd>down</kbd> key I move the highlighted bar to `Ubuntu, with Linux 5.11.0-36-generic` -

[image]

Then, I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and let the system boot as usual. After the system boots and I login I am no longer bugged with the problem.