# What does this Icon means and why it disables my keyboard?

Tags: gnome, keyboard, shortcut-keys, icons

So for some reason I watch something or just use my pc, out of nowhere this

[image]

shows on the screen and I don't know what it means, but it disables my keyboard shortcuts, and it doesn't work until I restart.

Some rare case if I try to type anything it doesn't let me :(
Can anyone help me out here?

System info:

OS:Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS x86_64

*EDIT: okay so i used my own keyboard and removed the office keyboard it's working now and isn't getting disabled again and again.*

*why is the office keyboard having the issue?
keyboard is Logitech Media Keyboard K20*0

Comment: Have you tried [this solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/1340274/1222991)? The answer is for 20.04, but may work for 18.04 as well.

Comment: @matigo let's see if it works or not, I applied the method now

Comment: I assume you are on a Mac? That's a Mac icon not an Ubuntu one.

Comment: @darth_epoxy no sir i'm on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS now, i cropped the image because its my Office PC

Comment: On MAC this means you can't get  your keyboard brigtness on because it is too bright (it wouldn't make any sense)

Comment: @france1 office keyboard doesn't have anything like that, even I don't know why it's happening only on Logitech keyboard, my home keyboard works fine on Ubuntu.