# What does this sign means? What does it do?

Tags: gui

I get this when I press Pause/Play button.. but what does it do? what does it means??[See this image please](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tEW8n.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Keyboard stops working and a "No" symbol is on the screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1340265/keyboard-stops-working-and-a-no-symbol-is-on-the-screen)

Comment: Not a duplicate! This is just normal behavior when you press a media key while no media is playing.

Answer (score 1):

It mean "not allowed" as in some key pressed has no function in the context.

The Play/Pause works in compatible media player apps, not the desktop, therefore the icon is shown to indicate the key pressed does NOTHING.