# Ubuntu flashing not allowed sign after inserting headphone

Tags: 20.04, audio-jack

Since yesterday, whenever I am inserting my earphone into the headphone jack, Ubuntu keeps flashing not allowed sign. Also it automatically unpauses videos on youtube and spotify
I've checked with 2 different earphones, same issue.

[image: Here's a screenshot]

I have tried resetting pulseaudio by removing `~/.config/pulse` and `killall pulseaudio` but didn't work.

Any ideas on where is the problem and how to fix it?

Comment: That icon usually appears when the OS thinks you’re using it in tablet mode and receives input from the keyboard. [Take a look at this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1340274/1222991) and see if that resolves the issue 

Comment: The problem is not with the keyboard. It's with the headphone jack.

Comment: I understand what you originally wrote. The icon, however, generally appears as a result of keyboard-related conflicts. The link was to offer avenues of exploration and consideration, not a canonical answer 

Comment: It seems your headphones have a stuck or broken key somewhere.

Comment: @ChanganAuto tried with 2 different headphone. same issue.

Comment: If so the problem is likely to be in the connector itself. Try a live session to rule out hardware, it's that simple.