# Pc is getting hanged unexpectedly

Tags: 18.04, lenovo, ideapad

I am using ubuntu 18.04 on my lenovo (ideapad 510-151kb) laptop. From last few days my laptop is getting hanged suddenly with the below popup on the screen .
Please help me to resolve this issue.[image]

Comment: If you press the [Super] key or one of the [Fn] keys, does the symbol go away?

Comment: If i press any fn keys this popup will disappear but keyboard won’t function after that (i.e any key pressed will not be shown on the screen).also again after few seconds this popup appears again

Comment: [This might help](https://askubuntu.com/a/1340274/1222991) 