# keyboard is not working it shows notification

Tags: boot, networking, command-line, drivers, popup-ads

My laptop keyboard suddenly stops working after showing a notification sign, then starts working after I use show application in dash. The attached image shows the notification:

[image: No Can Do]

Please help me to get rid of this problem

Comment: Depending on your version of Ubuntu, [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1340274/1222991) might offer a solution.

Comment: sir it's pop os 21.10 please do the needfull sir

Comment: Pop! OS is a bit different from Ubuntu proper, so I can’t really help. I don’t know all the details of that OS and am unwilling to troubleshoot something I don’t use daily 

Comment: Thanks for your reply sir if you get any solution please help me. This prob  highly disturbed me day by day please do the needful sir