# Black square area with a stroked circle

Tags: keyboard

I recently switched over from Windows to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. I am regularly seeing a black square area with stroked circle as soon as I switch on my laptop.
Please help me with it. I am enclosing a screen shot of the same. My laptop is HP make.

[image]

Comment: Seems like you have a keyboard shortcut with an invalid action. Is your keyboard fine?

Comment: Depending on which HP you have, [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1340265/keyboard-stops-working-and-a-no-symbol-is-on-the-screen/1340274#1340274) may help ...