# How to solve the weird cancel popup icon in ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: icons

I am using ubuntu 20.04 and a big weird cancel icon pops up continuosly and letters can't be type at that time..It seriously giving me headache.How to solve it?

Edit:I figured out that when I enter some key(s) like f9 f10 f11 suddenly the icons pop out.But i don't know how to solve it.These keys works fine in bios or windows..but when i enter these keys in ubuntu..certainly the icon pops out.
PS:I don't wanna leave ubuntu,i like linux environment.
Please help me out.

[image: A big popup icon distracts to type]

Comment: That probably means some key that has no function in the desktop is being pressed. Likely a problem with your keyboard.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A weird cancel button keeps poping up and i can't type words properly](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1342432/a-weird-cancel-button-keeps-poping-up-and-i-cant-type-words-properly)

Comment: How to solve it?do you have any idea?

Comment: An hardware problem isn't solvable by software.

Comment: But everything goes fine on windows.why this thing in linux?

Comment: First, figure out which key(s) cause the error. Remember that we are not there, so we cannot methodically try every key on your keyboard for you.

Comment: And if it works in Windows that is something that should have been mentioned since the start. This is your third question about the same.

Comment: Hoe to figure it out,do you have any tips?

Comment: It constantly giving me headache..i reinstalled linux more than 5 times thinking the error will fade away but its not going easily

Comment: I have figured out tha f9 f10 f11 keys are the problem..what can i do next?

Comment: [Edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1343795/edit) and put this information inside.

Comment: I have now put it,guys help me

Comment: [Does this solution work for you?](https://askubuntu.com/a/1340274/1222991)

Comment: No it's still showing

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A weird cancel icon keep pops up](https://askubuntu.com/q/1342406/)

Comment: Please refrain from reposting the same question again.

Comment: What do you expect me to do.i switched to Microsoft windows now

Comment: I [answered](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1114091/f10-f11-f12-key-now-allowed-ubuntu-18-04-1-lts/1505851#1505851) in another earlier question, hope it helps.